# Does calling Observable.Subscribe multiple times create multiple subscriptions?

Tags: typescript, observable, subscription

Hello in my `Component` i  am using a `Service` method   which in turn  returns an `observable`. What i want to know is if  i call `Subscribe` multiple times  in the component will this create multiple subscriptions and thus in time break the application?

**Service method**

```
getClients():Observable<User[]>{

      let route=UserService.baseUrl+"/users";
      var data= this.http.get(route)
        .map(resp=>resp)
        .catch(error=>{console.log(error);return Observable.throw(JSON.stringify(error));}) as Observable<User[]>;
     return data;
```

**Component**

```
export class IndexComponent {

        private canPress:boolean;

        public enableButtons: boolean;

        public users: Array<User>;
        constructor(private userservice:UserService,private router:Router) {

        }
        private getUsers(){
            console.log("Entered init");

            this.userservice.getClients().subscribe(data=>{
                this.users=data;
                this.canPress=this.users.length>0;
            },error=>{
                console.log("From Index: Could not obtain users");
                this.users=UserService.users;
                console.log(this.users);
            });

        }
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getUsers(); 

        }

    }
```

If in my `HTML` i attach the `getUsers` method to a `click` event ...will i spawn new subscriptions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscription inside getUsers() is resolved when UserService.getClients http call emits event or error. Please do not panic and carry on.